# TestCafe and Yopmail

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

simple question

In end2end testing I want to check a few options, inner texts and links on yopmail in one of incoming mails. The problem occurred after .click on button "Check Inbox" with 404 result.
I looks like yopmail is successfully preventing automated testing.

Am I right, or there is a secret way to do it? and if answer is no, maybe you have some idea how to accomplish test where temporary mails have to be inspected

Comment: Could you please share an example of a test script that shows the issue?

Comment: well, its not as important actually, but you have down there example from Janaaaa with secrete code for chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with yopmail, but if all you care about is the contents of the email message, perhaps you could forward emails to a provider that doesn't block automation, such as protonmail, and check the contents there? Protonmail doesn't block me from checking/sending emails.

Comment: and if I want to make 10 tests per day with new created user accounts? i need new mail every time. That's why temporary mails like yopmaile etc. are great for this purpose and protonmail will not help

Answer (score 1):

**Secret Way :) (works in chrome only, fails in firefox):**

You go into the inbox directly by appending it to the URL.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe'

fixture`yopMail`
    .page`http://www.yopmail.com?emailme1997@yopmail.com`

    .before(async t => {
    })

    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.setTestSpeed(0.3)
        await t.maximizeWindow()
    })

test("hello", async t => {
    const chkMail = Selector('.slientext')
    await t.wait(3000)
    await t.click(chkMail);
    await t.wait(5000)
});
```

Comment: well, nice try! I also did it, but you still probably cant do anything like work with existing there messages, you cant click a particular mail and a link that's inside. And here is my problem.
let's say after await t.wait(5000) add another line - only to click first mail on the page 
await t.click(Selector('div[class="m"]'))

Comment: if there is more than one mail we need 
await t.click(Selector('div[class="m"]:first-of-type'))

Comment: result is still the same - we get error "1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree" and ITS NOT TRUE because if you go to page in chrome dev console in elements when you press ctrl+f and type this selector it will match

Comment: Add an expect and a timeout before you are trying to click it? await t.expect(Selector(the selector).visible).ok('Selector not visible', {timeout: 20000}). Then try to click it. Testcafe is very fast, sometimes UI elements don't load fast enough for test cafe and the element will not be there when it checks. You have to write  your code with that in mind.